Specifying large polygons in Django GEOS
I am getting results I don't understand when creating or combining polygons to cover most of the globe.
If I use one polygon, GEOS assumes the shortest boundary between coordinates. So the following specifies a 0.2° wide shape, not a 359.8° wide shape:
from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon, Polygon

Polygon([(-179.99, -85), (-179.99, 85), (179.99, 85), (179.99, -85), (-179.99, -85)], srid=4326)

So I create two polygons, so that each boundary is less than 180°, and combine in a multi-polygon:
west = Polygon(((0, 85), (-179, 85), (-179, -85), (0, -85), (0, 85)), srid=4326)
east = Polygon(((0, 85), (179, 85), (179, -85), (0, -85), (0, 85)), srid=4326)
big = MultiPolygon(east, west)
feature.geography = big
feature.save()

But I don't get any matches in the east:
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

queryset.filter(feature__geography__intersects=Point(-2.5, 2.5, srid=4326))  # match
queryset.filter(feature__geography__intersects=Point(-2.5, -2.5, srid=4326))  # match
queryset.filter(feature__geography__intersects=Point(2.5, -2.5, srid=4326))  # no match
queryset.filter(feature__geography__intersects=Point(2.5, 2.5, srid=4326))  # no match

If I just search on east, ie, feature.geography = east, all four of the above queries match.
If I split the globe into four zones along the equator like so:
northwest = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 85), (-179, 85), (-179, 0), (0, 0)), srid=4326)
northeast = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 85), (179, 85), (179, 0), (0, 0)), srid=4326)
southwest = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, -85), (-179, -85), (-179, 0), (0, 0)), srid=4326)
southeast = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, -85), (179, -85), (179, 0), (0, 0)), srid=4326)
big = MultiPolygon(northwest, northeast, southwest, southeast)

All four queries match.
I am completely perplexed.

Some of my results above must have been erroneous.
But GEOS does not always assume the shortest route between coordinates as suggested here. It seems to prefer going west not east from latitude zero. For example:
Polygon(((160, -85), (0, -85), (0, 85), (160, 85), (160, -85)), srid=4326)

wraps west from 0° through 180° (round the back of the globe) to 160°, even though the shorter route is eastwards.
Similarly:
Polygon(((0, 85), (-179, 85), (-179, -85), (0, -85), (0, 85)), srid=4326)

covers much of the west, as you'd expect. But start from latitude 1:
Polygon(((1, 85), (-179, 85), (-179, -85), (1, -85), (1, 85)), srid=4326)

covers the west but also wraps over the North Pole. (Starting from latitude 0.1 does not, I haven't tested between 0.1 and 1.)
To get round this, combine two polygons and join at lat 1, or four polygons NW, NE, SW, SE.
Also, ensure you visualize any shapes to catch any counter-intuitive shapes.
I'd greatly appreciate a proper set of rules, as this is clearly incomplete, hence not marking this as the answer.
